# How to contain escape sequences in macro definition #?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, stringification

I am trying to use this macro definition in C:

```
#define STR(x) #x
```

Is it possible to contain some escape sequences inside x? e.g., I want to define a string like:

```
char* str = "\'";
```

This declaration does not seem to work:

```
char* str1 = STR(\');
```

If I must use this macro definition, is there some way to contain strings containing apostrophe `"\'"`? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the preprocessor works like that.  Please explain exactly why you need this.  Also, since you've tagged C++, note that string literals cannot be assigned to a non-const `char*`.

Comment: In C++ you can use [raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), `std::string escaped = R"(\')"; std::cout << escaped;` -> `\'`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have a macro definition like:

#define IMG(x) "/Image/" #x ".png"

to describe the image's path and name. but some image's name contains apostrophe "'". is there some way to use my Macro definition to denote these images name?

Comment: You tagged two different languages. Since you mentioned C in the question, I'm assuming the C++ was the extraneous tag.

Comment: It seems you are trying to use the preprocessor to perform "stringization" on arbitrary text, but macro arguments are not allowed to be arbitrary text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```c
const char* img = "/Image/'.png";
```

can also be written as

```c
const char* img = "/Image/" "'" ".png";
```

so you could use

```c
#define IMG(x) "/Image/" x ".png"

const char* img = IMG("'");
```